# PHP script does not insert BLOB images into database, inserts name of the file instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, blob

Good morning!
Recently I've tried to insert images into database, alongside other String type data. It works great for String type data, but not for BLOB type images. I have noticed that only the name of the image is inserted, not the image. I am a beginner in PHP scripts and SQL databases. Can anybody help me?:)

```
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['yname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
      $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
       $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['url']);
       $color1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['color1']);
      $color2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['color2']);
    $contact1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contact1']);
     $contact2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contact2']);
     $contact3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contact3']);
         $contact4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contact4']);
          $bio = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['message']);
           $farewell = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['farewell']);
          $ppname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ppname']);
             $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
               $dadress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['dadress']);
             $version = "full";
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
  $filetmpname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $filename2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['name'];
  $filetmpname2 = $_FILES['uploadfile2']['tmp_name'];
  $folder = 'imagesuploadedf/';
 // edited and added below code. it will check if folder exists and create if not exists.....
 $foldername = 'imagesuploadedf';
 if ( ! is_dir($foldername)) {
     mkdir($foldername); }
 // end of edited and added code
  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $folder.$filename);
  move_uploaded_file($filetmpname2, $folder.$filename2);

// $sql = "INSERT INTO `uploadedimage` (`imagename`)  VALUES ('$filename')";
    // connect to mysql database using mysqli

    // mysql query to insert data
         $query = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`name`, `url`, `email`, `imagename`, `imagename2`, `color1`, `color2`, `contact1`, `contact2`, `contact3`, `contact4`, `bio`, `farewell`, `ppname`, `version`) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$filename', '$filename2', '$color1', '$color2', '$contact1', '$contact2', '$contact3', '$contact4', '$bio', '$farewell', '$ppname', '$version')";      
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`name`, `url`, `email`, `color1`, `color2`, `contact1`, `contact2`, `contact3`, `contact4`, `bio`, `farewell`, `ppname`, `version`, `dadress`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";    
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
  if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
      echo "Error";
  } else{
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssssss", $fname, $url, $lname, $color1, $color2, $contact1, $contact2, $contact3, $contact4, $bio, $farewell, $ppname, $version, $dadress);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
  $sql2 = "UPDATE tabela SET imagename = '$filename', imagename2 = '$filename2' WHERE ppname = '$ppname'";
   mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
```

Comment: You can't insert images in database, you can insert a reference of the image like name or location then show the image based on the name or location from database

Comment: @ChibaAndrei "_You can't insert images in database_" Sure?

Comment: Where are you trying to insert the image? I see column names like `imagename` and `imagename2`, but none for your images content

Comment: It's because your script doesn't attempt to put the image in the database, only its name.

Comment: @kerbholz you can insert the data from the image but it's easier to insert the name and location and get it as you have the image saved somewhere - nevermind, today i learned what a blob is :)

Comment: @ChibaAndrei _That_ is true, "_You can't insert images in database_" is not.

Comment: @kerbholz you are right, you can insert images

Comment: Have you got enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag of the form that you're using to upload images?

Answer (score 0):

If your BLOB field is `imagename` then instead of assigning image name to variable using `$filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']`, use this code to get the image data

```
$imageBlob = fopen($filetmpname, 'rb');
```

or

```
$imageBlob = file_get_content($filetmpname);
```

and then use this `$imageBlob` to store in DB column using simple update query.